# How to find if two line segments intersect in 3d?

Tags: geometry

I am trying to code an algorithm in Scala, programming language. The program will return false if the line segment intersects in 3D: I don't need to find the point of the intersection even if they intersect.

The problem is that I am not able to find the step by step mathematical method for the line segments, most of them are for lines: lines might intersect at some point, but line segment, given the specific length might not intersect in the given band.

> Given point A (Ax, Ay, Az), point B(Bx, By, Bz), point C(Cx, Cy, Cz), and
>   point D(Dx,Dy,Dz), does AB intersect CD? (True or False)

Comment: I would find the intersection of the lines, then check if it lies on both segments.

Answer (score 3):

Points on the line through $A$ and $B$ have the form $tA + (1-t)B$ for various real numbers $t$. The point will be on the line segment connecting $A$ and $B$ if and only if $0 \le t \le 1$. All other points on the line will have either $t < 0$ or $t > 1$. Similarly, points on the line segment connecting $C$ and $D$ have form $sC + (1-s)D$ for $0\le s \le 1$.

The intersection of the two lines must have both forms, giving the equation $$tA + (1-t)B = sC + (1-s)D$$
This is actually three equations in the two unknowns $t$ and $s$:

$$t(A_x - B_x) + s(D_x - C_x) = D_x - B_x\\t(A_y - B_y) + s(D_y - C_y) = D_y - B_y\\t(A_z - B_z) + s(D_z - C_z) = D_z - B_z$$

If these three equations have a simultaneous solution for $t$ and $s$ (solve two of them, then check the solution in the third), then the two lines intersect. If the solution also satisfies $0 \le t \le 1, 0 \le s \le 1$, then the segments intersect.